# cannot unlock login screen 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login-screen

When my computer boots, entering the correct password won't start my session. I found out the problem is /home/user/.Xauthority ownership. root owns this folder and giving the ownership to the user will solve the problem... for a while. I don't know how or when, but the ownership will go back to root pretty often; It can happen just after one boot or ten.

Is there a definitive solution to this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to change your behaviour. **Don't** run GUI apps (like *nautilus* for instance) by calling them from terminal with `sudo ...`.